# How to externally change a state variable belonging to a React Native default class so that it re-renders

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my app, I have defined a default class A in module xyz.js that renders a page on my navigation stack. Depending on one of class A's state variables, the views that are rendered differ. For example, if the app is placed in an "edit mode", then an editing view is rendered in addition to the other standard views rendered when the app is not in the "edit mode". I can't figure out how to change that state variable and cause the instantiation of class A to re-render.

Here is what I have:

Module abc.js:

```
import XYZ from './xyz';
import {Edit} from './xyz';
import { pencilEditButton } from './Images';

const App = createStackNavigator(
{
    Home: {
        screen: My App,

        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: 'myApp',

            headerRight: (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={() => EditMix()}
                    underlayColor="gray">
                    <View>
                        <Image source={pencilEditButton} style={styles.navigationButtonImage} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
            ),
        }),
    },
}
);

export default createAppContainer(App);
```

Module xyz.js:

```
export default class XYZ extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        editMode: false,    
    };
  };

render() {
  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           { this.state.editMode === true ?
             <TouchableHighlight 
                    onPress={this._onXPressed} 
                    underlayColor="white">
                <View style={[styles.flowRight, styles.controlButton]}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{'Edit Mode'}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
             :

             <TouchableHighlight 
                    onPress={this._onYPressed} 
                    underlayColor="white">
                <View style={[styles.flowRight, styles.controlButton]}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{'Non Edit Mode'}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
           }
        </View>
     );
   }
 }

export  function Edit() {
   editMode = true;
   alert('User wants to edit!');
}
```

So as you can see, there is a named function called "Edit()" at the bottom of module xyz.js. This function is called from module abc.js when the edit button is pressed. When the edit button is pressed, the alert view is displayed, but the XYZ function is not re-rendered. How do I correctly update the state variable "editMode" inside the instantiated XYZ class and how do I cause it to re-render?

Comment: Maybe a global state might help you(https://redux.js.org/).